# Using computed field to format phone numbers?

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to create a computer field that automatically formats phone numbers like so: xxx.xxx.xxxx

The numbers come from user input, and they will be displayed on each user page (I've added fields to Drupal's user profiles so that they include contact info)

How do I do that? Never used computed fields before, but I believe it's the solution to what I'm trying to do....

Comment: where the phone number is coming from - user submits a form?

Comment: In addition to "where from", please also tell us where are you planning to display them, as this might affect the answers.

Comment: Hi @oksana-c and @Molot! Thanks for commenting.... The numbers come from user input, and they will be displayed on each user page (I've added fields to drupals users so that they include contact info)

Comment: please edit this into your question. Also, you added fields to user profiles, not users ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Masked Input](https://www.drupal.org/project/masked_input) module. It allows you to create a text field with mask that you can setup custom (e.g. 999.999.9999). When user enters info into the field with masked input, the information entered is formatted automatically and stored into database with that exact format. So the output of formatted information becomes that much easier.

One drawback of this module is that it provides formatting only if user has JS enabled in the browser. If JS is disabled, you will rely on user to enter info in the desirable format. You can also ask the user to provide info in specific format by entering field description as a fallback (e.g. "Enter your phone number as follows - xxx.xxx.xxxx). 
I've used this module on websites with big user base, and I can tell that users very rarely have JS disabled when they fill up forms.

Comment: Hm, is there a way to it without downloading a module?